# Overlapping Modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am attempting to set a condition that a modal will display after a time increment if a cookie is not set and if another modal isn't currently visible. Here is the script I am using. This isn't working for some reason.

```
jQuery(function($) {
        function showModal(){
            console.log("HERE")
            $("#modal1").modal('show')
        }
        if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null && $('#modal2').is(':hidden')) {
            modalAlert();
        }
        var timeout;
        function modalAlert(){
            timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){showModal();},10000);
            $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        }
});
```

What would be ideal is if '#modal2' is visible, after it is dismissed it resets the counter on displaying '#modal1'.

Comment: Can you describe what "isn't working"? It's always a good idea to check that another modal isn't visible, but you're checking specifically that `#modal2` is hidden. What I'd recommend is that you create a function which will check that all of your modals are not visible and if one is visible, then don't continue, or else, continue.

Comment: So presently what is happening is that #modal1 is set to display after a 10 second delay. This is happening regardless of whether or not #modal2 is visible (#modal2 is activated via a link on the page). #modal1 fires and is displayed overtop of #modal2.